# Progress bar Loading Disappear

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar

how to make Progress Bar loading till all the methods in doBackground() is executed.I have used Thread.sleep by which the loader is displaying after that it takes the pause executes all the methods and then returns to next activiy

```
 public  class LoadDataForActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Do some long running operation on a worker thread
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(200); // no need for a loop
                    cities_from();
                    cities_to();
                    srs_bus();
                    etsPick();
                    etsPick1();
                    srs_drop1();
                    srs_drop2();
                    srs_key_value();
                    key_value();
                    srs_pick1();
                    srs_pick2();
                    key_value_pick();
                    vrl_borad_id_loc();
                    vrl_board_key_value();
                    vrl_drop_id_loc();
                    vrl_drop_key_value();
                    vrl_bus();
                    bitla_key_value_pick2();
                    ets_bus();
                    bitla_drop();
                    bitla_drop1();
                    bitla_drop2();
                    bitla_key_value();
                    bitla_key_value1();
                    bitla_pick1();
                    bitla_pick2();
                    bitla();
                    srs();
                    tabs();
                    cancel_policy();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("LongOperation", "Interrupted", e);

                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(BusOperators.this);
        pd.setTitle("Title");
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait.... ");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            super.onPostExecute(v);
            pd.dismiss();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // Update UI to show progress
    /* prgDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); */
    }

}
```

I want the progress bar to remain till all the methods in doBackground() gets executed

Answer (score 1):

You have to set:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
```

before you start running the thread, and in `onPostExecute` set:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(GONE)
```

Comment: i have used Progesss dialog pd= new ProgressDialog(this);pd.show(); in preExecute() and pd.dismiss() in postExecute() but the loading animation is rotating and then stops for few seconds and the page is loaded. I want the loading animation to rotate till the page is completely loaded

Comment: First of all you need to declare your progress bar in xml as well, and in activity just find out like this:

ProgressBar pd;
pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.your_pb_id);
pd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) -> in preExecute();
pd.setVisibility(View.GONE) - > in onPostExecute();

I never used show() and dismiss() for progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

When using `executor.execute` the control will directly return and the control will go to the method `onPostExecute`

Just unwrap your code inside the `doInBackground` method from `executor.execute`

Comment: the loading animation is not vissible

Comment: Do your methods like `cities_from()` run in separate background thread?